# Need help editing script to move multiple rows to another tab to include one more field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RaZXsOND3GptpD8W7CZPA6ntjChDp8Dmc6PMMhRBCJw/edit?usp=sharing

Ok, the script works BUT I can't pin point the fields that I want to move.
Its just the Date field actually. I don't want the text field A3 to move just the manually typed in field in B3..and then everything else below it.

Here is the current code I'm using that I found here and tailored to fit our needs just can't get that ONE field. Sure its something simple, just can't focus so hoping someone might help:

```
function reMove() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");

  //max 7 to Archive 
  for(var a=0;a<200;a++){

    var values = sourceSheet.getRange("A4:BY100").getValues();

      for(var v=0;v<values.length;v++){

        //row J, index 9
        if(values[v][3] !==  ""){

           destinationSheet.appendRow(values[v]);
           sourceSheet.deleteRow(v+1);
           break;

        }
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to correctly understand about your question. So can I ask you about your question? 1. In your shared Spreadsheet, what is the sheet of `UPLOAD`? 3. In your script, the sheet of `Archive` is used at `var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");`. But in your shared Spreadsheet, there is not sheet of `Archive`. How about this? 3. Can you provide the result you expect?

Comment: Hello Tanaike, 
The file has been edited multiple time since I posted but tried to get it back to its original state.
1. UPLOAD is the main page where the csv file is to be uploaded (Imported) by staff.
2. What I shared here is the original script not what is in the shared sheet. I edited above to match my needs. Archive in my Sheet is Process.
3. When the button is pressed, B3 and A4 to BY100 is moved to the tab labeled Process. NOT the text in A3 it needs to stay on that page so they know where to enter the date manually.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code that does exactly what I needed it to do ...

```
function reMove() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getSheetByName('UPLOAD').getRange('A3:BY');
  var values = range.getValues().filter(function (r) {return r[0]})
  values[0][0] = null;
  range.offset(1, 0).clear()
 ss.getSheetByName("Process").clear().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[1].length).setValues(values)
}
```